# "Needs a positive frequency of recurrence" google apps clock trigger

Tags: triggers, google-apps-script, builder, clock

I am having trouble with a clock based trigger I am trying to create.  This is for google apps script.  This script is supposed to call a function that will email information at 5 am from a spreadsheet.  I know the function works because I had used it with the 5 am to 6 am built in trigger, but they want it at exactly 5 am and not anytime in that hour range.  Here is my code:

```
var SOD_Briefing_Trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendBriefingByEmail")
.timeBased().
atHour(5)
.create();
```

Everytime I try to run or debug it I get an error message of:

```
Needs a positive frequency of recurrence
```

Sorry if this seems like a newb question.  I spent a few days searching here and google generally for a similar issue.  I could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message *is* a bit cryptic. If you just say "atHour", the system knows the "time" but not the "frequency".

This following should work.

```
var SOD_Briefing_Trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendBriefingByEmail")
.timeBased()
.atHour(5)
.everyDays(1)
.create();
```

Note the "everyDays" call. That means run it every X day(s)  -every day in this call. You can change it to other frequencies based on the calls documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_clocktriggerbuilder). Some other examples - "atDate" (if you just want it run today or tomrorow) and "onWeekDay" (if you want it run every Monday for eg.).

Comment: So far seems to be working.  I will have to wait until 5 am to know for sure.  Is there any issue with the time zone?  Will it work off of the time zone of the spreadsheet or do you need to programatically set that too?

Comment: By default, triggers with time info assume the timezone of the script creator. You can change that by adding in the Trigger creation process by adding the "inTimezone" method. If you want to get the Timezone of the actual end user, then the only workaround is to find a spreadsheet in that user's drive and ask it - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet#getSpreadsheetTimeZone

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work once by using a simple function that just sent me an email with a short message.  I have since not been able to get it to work to send me the longer email based off the spreadsheet.

Here is the entire code I was trying to run, that did not send me anything at 0500 today.

```
function createTimeTrigger3() {

  try{



  var SOD_Briefing_TriggerMonday = ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendBriefingByEmail2")
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(5)
      .nearMinute(15)
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
      .create();

    var SOD_Briefing_TriggerTuesday = ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendBriefingByEmail2")
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(5)
        .nearMinute(15)
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY)
        .create();

    var SOD_Briefing_TriggerWednesday = ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendBriefingByEmail2")
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(5)
        .nearMinute(15)
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY)
        .create();

    var SOD_Briefing_TriggerThursday = ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendBriefingByEmail2")
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(5)
        .nearMinute(15)
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY)
        .create();

    var SOD_Briefing_TriggerFriday = ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendBriefingByEmail2")
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(5)
        .nearMinute(15)
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY)
        .create();


  }
  catch(err)
  {
     MailApp.sendEmail("************.gov", "there was a problem with the SOD trigger", err.message);

}

   Logger.log("Unique ID of SOD_Briefing_TriggerMonday: " + SOD_Briefing_TriggerMonday.getUniqueId());
    Logger.log("Unique ID of SOD_Briefing_TriggerTuesday: " + SOD_Briefing_TriggerTuesday.getUniqueId());
    Logger.log("Unique ID of SOD_Briefing_TriggerWednesday: " + SOD_Briefing_TriggerWednesday.getUniqueId());
    Logger.log("Unique ID of SOD_Briefing_TriggerThursday: " + SOD_Briefing_TriggerThursday.getUniqueId());
    Logger.log("Unique ID of SOD_Briefing_TriggerFriday: " + SOD_Briefing_TriggerFriday.getUniqueId());
      Logger.log("Unique ID of SOD_Briefing_TriggerToday: " + SOD_Briefing_TriggerToday.getUniqueId());


}

function sendBriefingByEmail2() {


  var email = SpreadsheetApp.openById("***********").getSheetByName("Email Roster").getRange(4, 3).getValue()
      +SpreadsheetApp.openById("***************").getSheetByName("Email Roster").getRange(5, 3).getValue()
      +SpreadsheetApp.openById("***************").getSheetByName("Email Roster").getRange(6, 3).getValue()
      +SpreadsheetApp.openById("***************").getSheetByName("Email Roster").getRange(7, 3).getValue()
      +SpreadsheetApp.openById("*************").getSheetByName("Email Roster").getRange(8, 3).getValue()
      +SpreadsheetApp.openById("*********************").getSheetByName("Email Roster").getRange(9, 3).getValue()
      +SpreadsheetApp.openById("**********************").getSheetByName("Email Roster").getRange(10, 3).getValue()
      +SpreadsheetApp.openById("**************").getSheetByName("Email Roster").getRange(11, 3).getValue()
      +SpreadsheetApp.openById("**********************").getSheetByName("Email Roster").getRange(12, 3).getValue();

      if (SpreadsheetApp.openById("**********************").getSheetByName("Previous_24_Hours").getRange(2, 1).isBlank()){

        try {

      MailApp.sendEmail(email, "No SOD Daily Briefing to Report Today", "There were no daily briefing entries submitted for SOD in the previous 24 hours.");

        }

        catch(err){ 
  MailApp.sendEmail("*************.gov", "there was a problem sending the SOD BLANK briefing in the AM", err.message);
}


        }




    else {

      try {

  var subject = "Special Operations Bureau Daily Briefing";

  var row = 2;

      var email24sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("*********************").getSheetByName("Previous_24_Hours");


  var LastRow = SpreadsheetApp.openById("******************").getSheetByName("Previous_24_Hours").getLastRow();




  var msgHtml = ""

      do {
      msgHtml = msgHtml + "<br><hr><br>"

      +"<p>"+"<b>"+"Unit: "+"</b>"+email24sheet.getRange(row, 11).getValue()+"</p>"
      +"<p>"+"<b>"+"Incident: "+"</b>"+email24sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue()+"</p>"
      +"<p>"+"<b>"+"Date / Time: "+"</b>"+email24sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue()+ " @ " + email24sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue()+ " hours"+"</p>"
      +"<p>"+"<b>"+"Location: " + "</b>" +email24sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue()+"</p>"      
        +"<p>"+"<b>"+"Trooper: "+"</b>"+email24sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue()+"</p>"
        +"<p>"+"<b>"+"Assisting Trooper(s): "+"</b>"+email24sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue()+"</p>"
     +"<p>"+"<b>"+"Suspect: "+"</b>"+email24sheet.getRange(row, 7).getValue()+"</p>"
       +"<p>"+"<b>"+"Charges: "+"</b>"+email24sheet.getRange(row, 8).getValue()+"</p>"
      +"<p>"+"<b>"+"Yield: "+"</b>"+email24sheet.getRange(row, 9).getValue()+"</p>"
          +"<p>"+"<b>"+"Synopsis: "+"</b>"+email24sheet.getRange(row, 10).getValue()+"</p>";
row = row + 1;

} while(row < LastRow+1);


  var msgHeader = "<p>"+"<H1>"+"<P ALIGN=Center>"+"Special Operations Bureau Daily Briefing"+"</H1>"+"</p>"
        +"<p>"+"<H2>"+"<P ALIGN=Center>"+"Created: " + new Date().toLocaleDateString()+"</H2>"+"</p>";

  var msgFooter = "<p>"+"<i>"+"<P ALIGN=Center>"+"This message was automatically generated using data submitted electronically from the Spec Ops Bureau website and / or form.  For errors or suggestions for improvements, email **************.gov "+"</i>"+"</p>";

    var msgPlain = msgHtml.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""); // clear html tags for plain mail


  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, msgPlain, { htmlBody: msgHeader + msgHtml + msgFooter });

    SpreadsheetApp.openById("*************").getSheetByName("Previous_24_Hours").getRange("Previous_24_Data").clearContent(); //clears the incidents that were just sent

  }

catch(err){ 
  MailApp.sendEmail("**************.gov", "there was a problem sending the SOD briefing in the AM", err.message);
}

}

  }
```

I was getting nothing at 0500.  I then tried to make more triggers just to test the trigger builder and try different things to see what I could make work.

I used the command I found from the google script site (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/managing_triggers_programmatically) to delete the triggers:

```
// Delete a trigger with the given unique ID
function deleteTrigger(triggerId) {
  // Locate a trigger by unique ID
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();
  // Loop over all triggers
  for(var i=0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    if (allTriggers[i].getUniqueId() == triggerId) {
      // Found the trigger and now delete it
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

But now I am getting:

> This script has too many triggers. Triggers must be deleted from the
>   script before more can be added.

and

> Already setting up a recurring clock trigger.

as error messages emailed to me when I try to run anything.

Should I instead do a different function for each day of the week's trigger?